# fasterxml.jackson parse wrong Class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I found that fasterxml.jackson parse wrong class in my project.
I have this controller method:

```
@PutMapping
public Course updateCourse(@RequestBody CourseDto course) {
    LoggedUser.logIn(authenticationFacade.getAuthentication().getName());
    Course courseEntity = converter.convert(course);
    return courseService.updateCourse(courseEntity);
}
```

But when I send PUT request to the API, I got this log:

```
2018-12-16 13:36:58.339  WARN 9400 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: 
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 93, column: 1]Object id [3] (for `server.crm.entities.Course`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 27, column: 24], Object id [3] (for `server.crm.entities.Course`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 46, column: 24], Object id [3] (for `server.crm.entities.Course`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 65, column: 24], Object id [3] (for `server.crm.entities.Course`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 84, column: 24].]
```

You can see that it tried to parse server.crm.entities.Course instead of CourseDto like I did after @RequestBody.

Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: the `@PutMapping` seems to be incomplete. http://appsdeveloperblog.com/putmapping-spring-mvc/

Comment: It just a snippet, I have @RequestMapping for Controller class and it works except this.

Comment: Try removing `@RequestBody`

Comment: @TranNgocKhoa the `PUT` might require different configuration that the `GET`. using `curl` in order to determine how a valid `PUT` has to look alike might help there.

Comment: @user7294900 it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you add the json you send up, and the code for the Course and CourseDto? Also, what's the converter?